# Java method direct invocation vs single element loop invocation

Tags: java, performance, jvm-hotspot, jmh, dtrace

Recently I wanted to see what is the performance difference invoking a method on an object directly, vs invoking the same method on the same object, If that objected is added in a single element ArrayList and we try to loop that one element List.

To be honest my assumption was that there would be small difference, as i would expect the single element loop to be unrolled, hence the invocation to mimic a direct invocation.

To test that I created the below simple JMH example: https://gist.github.com/nikkatsa/69a58c63c1b79b245d700f6465bce7f7

To my surprise invoking the method directly on the element seems to be ~2,5x faster. Which is a significant number, as my expectation totally different:

```
Benchmark                                                     Mode  Cnt          Score         Error  Units
SingleElementLoopBenchmark.directInvocation                  thrpt   10  332576972.176 ± 2740616.755  ops/s
SingleElementLoopBenchmark.singleElementLoopInvocation       thrpt   10  130179329.978 ± 1303776.248  ops/s
```

I tweeted a bit asking for some pointers to understand why that was happenning. I was told that running `perf` will give me a clue. So i did run with `-perf dtraceasm` and I got the below two outputs, the first for the direct invocation and the second for the looped one:

```
....[Hottest Region 1]..............................................................................
c2, com.benchmarks.loops.generated.SingleElementLoopBenchmark_directInvocation_jmhTest::directInvocation_thrpt_jmhStub, version 115 (69 bytes)

            0x000000010b73c92c: mov    %rbp,%r9
            0x000000010b73c92f: movzbl 0x94(%r9),%r10d                ;*getfield isDone {reexecute=0 rethrow=0 return_oop=0}
                                                                      ; - com.benchmarks.loops.generated.SingleElementLoopBenchmark_directInvocation_jmhTest::directInvocation_thrpt_jmhStub@27 (line 123)
                                                                      ; implicit exception: dispatches to 0x000000010b73ca5e
            0x000000010b73c937: test   %r10d,%r10d
            0x000000010b73c93a: jne    0x000000010b73c9da             ;*ifeq {reexecute=0 rethrow=0 return_oop=0}
                                                                      ; - com.benchmarks.loops.generated.SingleElementLoopBenchmark_directInvocation_jmhTest::directInvocation_thrpt_jmhStub@30 (line 123)
            0x000000010b73c940: mov    $0x1,%ebp
            0x000000010b73c945: data16 data16 nopw 0x0(%rax,%rax,1)   ;*aload_1 {reexecute=0 rethrow=0 return_oop=0}
                                                                      ; - com.benchmarks.loops.generated.SingleElementLoopBenchmark_directInvocation_jmhTest::directInvocation_thrpt_jmhStub@33 (line 124)
  9.56%  ↗  0x000000010b73c950: mov    0x40(%rsp),%r10
  1.00%  │  0x000000010b73c955: mov    0xc(%r10),%r10d                ;*getfield dispatcher {reexecute=0 rethrow=0 return_oop=0}
         │                                                            ; - com.benchmarks.loops.SingleElementLoopBenchmark::directInvocation@1 (line 23)
         │                                                            ; - com.benchmarks.loops.generated.SingleElementLoopBenchmark_directInvocation_jmhTest::directInvocation_thrpt_jmhStub@17 (line 121)
  0.17%  │  0x000000010b73c959: mov    0xc(%r12,%r10,8),%r11d         ; implicit exception: dispatches to 0x000000010b73ca12
 11.18%  │  0x000000010b73c95e: test   %r11d,%r11d
  0.00%  │  0x000000010b73c961: je     0x000000010b73c9c9             ;*invokevirtual performAction {reexecute=0 rethrow=0 return_oop=0}
         │                                                            ; - com.benchmarks.loops.SingleElementLoopBenchmark$Dispatcher::invoke@5 (line 40)
         │                                                            ; - com.benchmarks.loops.SingleElementLoopBenchmark::directInvocation@5 (line 23)
         │                                                            ; - com.benchmarks.loops.generated.SingleElementLoopBenchmark_directInvocation_jmhTest::directInvocation_thrpt_jmhStub@17 (line 121)
 10.69%  │  0x000000010b73c963: mov    %r9,(%rsp)
  0.65%  │  0x000000010b73c967: mov    0x38(%rsp),%rsi
  0.00%  │  0x000000010b73c96c: mov    $0x1,%edx
  0.14%  │  0x000000010b73c971: xchg   %ax,%ax
 10.08%  │  0x000000010b73c973: callq  0x000000010b6c2900             ; ImmutableOopMap{[48]=Oop [56]=Oop [64]=Oop [0]=Oop }
         │                                                            ;*invokevirtual consume {reexecute=0 rethrow=0 return_oop=0}
         │                                                            ; - com.benchmarks.loops.SingleElementLoopBenchmark$Listener::performAction@2 (line 53)
         │                                                            ; - com.benchmarks.loops.SingleElementLoopBenchmark$Dispatcher::invoke@5 (line 40)
         │                                                            ; - com.benchmarks.loops.SingleElementLoopBenchmark::directInvocation@5 (line 23)
         │                                                            ; - com.benchmarks.loops.generated.SingleElementLoopBenchmark_directInvocation_jmhTest::directInvocation_thrpt_jmhStub@17 (line 121)
         │                                                            ;   {optimized virtual_call}
  1.44%  │  0x000000010b73c978: mov    (%rsp),%r9
  0.19%  │  0x000000010b73c97c: movzbl 0x94(%r9),%r8d                 ;*ifeq {reexecute=0 rethrow=0 return_oop=0}
         │                                                            ; - com.benchmarks.loops.generated.SingleElementLoopBenchmark_directInvocation_jmhTest::directInvocation_thrpt_jmhStub@30 (line 123)
  9.77%  │  0x000000010b73c984: mov    0x108(%r15),%r10
  0.99%  │  0x000000010b73c98b: add    $0x1,%rbp                      ; ImmutableOopMap{r9=Oop [48]=Oop [56]=Oop [64]=Oop }
         │                                                            ;*ifeq {reexecute=1 rethrow=0 return_oop=0}
         │                                                            ; - com.benchmarks.loops.generated.SingleElementLoopBenchmark_directInvocation_jmhTest::directInvocation_thrpt_jmhStub@30 (line 123)
  0.02%  │  0x000000010b73c98f: test   %eax,(%r10)                    ;   {poll}
  0.28%  │  0x000000010b73c992: test   %r8d,%r8d
  0.00%  ╰  0x000000010b73c995: je     0x000000010b73c950             ;*aload_1 {reexecute=0 rethrow=0 return_oop=0}
                                                                      ; - com.benchmarks.loops.generated.SingleElementLoopBenchmark_directInvocation_jmhTest::directInvocation_thrpt_jmhStub@33 (line 124)
            0x000000010b73c997: movabs $0x10abd7d62,%r10
            0x000000010b73c9a1: callq  *%r10                          ;*invokestatic nanoTime {reexecute=0 rethrow=0 return_oop=0}
                                                                      ; - com.benchmarks.loops.generated.SingleElementLoopBenchmark_directInvocation_jmhTest::directInvocation_thrpt_jmhStub@34 (line 124)
            0x000000010b73c9a4: mov    0x30(%rsp),%r10
            0x000000010b73c9a9: mov    %rbp,0x18(%r10)                ;*putfield measuredOps {reexecute=0 rethrow=0 return_oop=0}
                                                                      ; - com.benchmarks.loops.generated.SingleElementLoopBenchmark_directInvocation_jmhTest::directInvocation_thrpt_jmhStub@49 (line 126)
            0x000000010b73c9ad: mov    %rax,0x30(%r10)                ;*putfield stopTime {reexecute=0 rethrow=0 return_oop=0}
                                                                      ; - com.benchmarks.loops.generated.SingleElementLoopBenchmark_directInvocation_jmhTest::directInvocation_thrpt_jmhStub@37 (line 124)
            0x000000010b73c9b1: movq   $0x0,0x20(%r10)                ;*invokevirtual directInvocation {reexecute=0 rethrow=0 return_oop=0}
....................................................................................................
```

```
....[Hottest Region 1]..............................................................................
c2, com.benchmarks.loops.generated.SingleElementLoopBenchmark_singleElementLoopInvocation_jmhTest::singleElementLoopInvocation_thrpt_jmhStub, version 115 (279 bytes)

                                                                        ; - com.benchmarks.loops.generated.SingleElementLoopBenchmark_singleElementLoopInvocation_jmhTest::singleElementLoopInvocation_thrpt_jmhStub@27 (line 123)
                                                                        ; implicit exception: dispatches to 0x000000011153fffe
              0x000000011153fa81: test   %r10d,%r10d
              0x000000011153fa84: jne    0x000000011153fbe4             ;*ifeq {reexecute=0 rethrow=0 return_oop=0}
                                                                        ; - com.benchmarks.loops.generated.SingleElementLoopBenchmark_singleElementLoopInvocation_jmhTest::singleElementLoopInvocation_thrpt_jmhStub@30 (line 123)
              0x000000011153fa8a: mov    0x58(%rsp),%rdx
              0x000000011153fa8f: test   %rdx,%rdx
              0x000000011153fa92: je     0x000000011153fd5e
              0x000000011153fa98: mov    $0x1,%ebx
         ╭    0x000000011153fa9d: jmp    0x000000011153fad6
  0.19%  │ ↗  0x000000011153fa9f: mov    0x58(%rsp),%r13
  3.55%  │ │  0x000000011153faa4: mov    (%rsp),%rcx
  0.09%  │ │  0x000000011153faa8: mov    0x60(%rsp),%rdx
  0.22%  │ │  0x000000011153faad: mov    0x50(%rsp),%r11
  0.17%  │ │  0x000000011153fab2: mov    0x8(%rsp),%rbx                 ;*if_icmpge {reexecute=0 rethrow=0 return_oop=0}
         │ │                                                            ; - com.benchmarks.loops.SingleElementLoopBenchmark$Dispatcher::invokeInLoop@12 (line 44)
         │ │                                                            ; - com.benchmarks.loops.SingleElementLoopBenchmark::singleElementLoopInvocation@5 (line 28)
         │ │                                                            ; - com.benchmarks.loops.generated.SingleElementLoopBenchmark_singleElementLoopInvocation_jmhTest::singleElementLoopInvocation_thrpt_jmhStub@17 (line 121)
  3.55%  │↗│  0x000000011153fab7: movzbl 0x94(%r11),%r8d                ;*goto {reexecute=0 rethrow=0 return_oop=0}
         │││                                                            ; - com.benchmarks.loops.SingleElementLoopBenchmark$Dispatcher::invokeInLoop@35 (line 44)
         │││                                                            ; - com.benchmarks.loops.SingleElementLoopBenchmark::singleElementLoopInvocation@5 (line 28)
         │││                                                            ; - com.benchmarks.loops.generated.SingleElementLoopBenchmark_singleElementLoopInvocation_jmhTest::singleElementLoopInvocation_thrpt_jmhStub@17 (line 121)
  0.16%  │││  0x000000011153fabf: mov    0x108(%r15),%r10
  0.28%  │││  0x000000011153fac6: add    $0x1,%rbx                      ; ImmutableOopMap{r11=Oop rcx=Oop rdx=Oop r13=Oop }
         │││                                                            ;*ifeq {reexecute=1 rethrow=0 return_oop=0}
         │││                                                            ; - com.benchmarks.loops.generated.SingleElementLoopBenchmark_singleElementLoopInvocation_jmhTest::singleElementLoopInvocation_thrpt_jmhStub@30 (line 123)
  0.19%  │││  0x000000011153faca: test   %eax,(%r10)                    ;   {poll}
  4.00%  │││  0x000000011153facd: test   %r8d,%r8d
         │││  0x000000011153fad0: jne    0x000000011153fbe9             ;*aload_1 {reexecute=0 rethrow=0 return_oop=0}
         │││                                                            ; - com.benchmarks.loops.generated.SingleElementLoopBenchmark_singleElementLoopInvocation_jmhTest::singleElementLoopInvocation_thrpt_jmhStub@33 (line 124)
  0.07%  ↘││  0x000000011153fad6: mov    0xc(%rcx),%r8d                 ;*getfield dispatcher {reexecute=0 rethrow=0 return_oop=0}
          ││                                                            ; - com.benchmarks.loops.SingleElementLoopBenchmark::singleElementLoopInvocation@1 (line 28)
          ││                                                            ; - com.benchmarks.loops.generated.SingleElementLoopBenchmark_singleElementLoopInvocation_jmhTest::singleElementLoopInvocation_thrpt_jmhStub@17 (line 121)
  0.22%   ││  0x000000011153fada: mov    0x10(%r12,%r8,8),%r10d         ;*getfield singleListenerList {reexecute=0 rethrow=0 return_oop=0}
          ││                                                            ; - com.benchmarks.loops.SingleElementLoopBenchmark$Dispatcher::invokeInLoop@4 (line 44)
          ││                                                            ; - com.benchmarks.loops.SingleElementLoopBenchmark::singleElementLoopInvocation@5 (line 28)
          ││                                                            ; - com.benchmarks.loops.generated.SingleElementLoopBenchmark_singleElementLoopInvocation_jmhTest::singleElementLoopInvocation_thrpt_jmhStub@17 (line 121)
          ││                                                            ; implicit exception: dispatches to 0x000000011153ff2a
  0.21%   ││  0x000000011153fadf: mov    0x8(%r12,%r10,8),%edi          ; implicit exception: dispatches to 0x000000011153ff3e
  4.39%   ││  0x000000011153fae4: cmp    $0x237565,%edi                 ;   {metadata(&apos;com/nikoskatsanos/benchmarks/loops/SingleElementLoopBenchmark$Dispatcher$1&apos;)}
          ││  0x000000011153faea: jne    0x000000011153fc92
  0.33%   ││  0x000000011153faf0: lea    (%r12,%r10,8),%r9              ;*invokeinterface size {reexecute=0 rethrow=0 return_oop=0}
          ││                                                            ; - com.benchmarks.loops.SingleElementLoopBenchmark$Dispatcher::invokeInLoop@7 (line 44)
          ││                                                            ; - com.benchmarks.loops.SingleElementLoopBenchmark::singleElementLoopInvocation@5 (line 28)
          ││                                                            ; - com.benchmarks.loops.generated.SingleElementLoopBenchmark_singleElementLoopInvocation_jmhTest::singleElementLoopInvocation_thrpt_jmhStub@17 (line 121)
  0.09%   ││  0x000000011153faf4: mov    0x10(%r9),%r9d
  0.14%   ││  0x000000011153faf8: test   %r9d,%r9d
          ╰│  0x000000011153fafb: jle    0x000000011153fab7             ;*if_icmpge {reexecute=0 rethrow=0 return_oop=0}
           │                                                            ; - com.benchmarks.loops.SingleElementLoopBenchmark$Dispatcher::invokeInLoop@12 (line 44)
           │                                                            ; - com.benchmarks.loops.SingleElementLoopBenchmark::singleElementLoopInvocation@5 (line 28)
           │                                                            ; - com.benchmarks.loops.generated.SingleElementLoopBenchmark_singleElementLoopInvocation_jmhTest::singleElementLoopInvocation_thrpt_jmhStub@17 (line 121)
  3.98%    │  0x000000011153fafd: lea    (%r12,%r8,8),%rdi              ;*getfield dispatcher {reexecute=0 rethrow=0 return_oop=0}
           │                                                            ; - com.benchmarks.loops.SingleElementLoopBenchmark::singleElementLoopInvocation@1 (line 28)
           │                                                            ; - com.benchmarks.loops.generated.SingleElementLoopBenchmark_singleElementLoopInvocation_jmhTest::singleElementLoopInvocation_thrpt_jmhStub@17 (line 121)
  0.06%    │  0x000000011153fb01: xor    %r9d,%r9d                      ;*aload_0 {reexecute=0 rethrow=0 return_oop=0}
           │                                                            ; - com.benchmarks.loops.SingleElementLoopBenchmark$Dispatcher::invokeInLoop@15 (line 45)
           │                                                            ; - com.benchmarks.loops.SingleElementLoopBenchmark::singleElementLoopInvocation@5 (line 28)
           │                                                            ; - com.benchmarks.loops.generated.SingleElementLoopBenchmark_singleElementLoopInvocation_jmhTest::singleElementLoopInvocation_thrpt_jmhStub@17 (line 121)
  0.09%    │  0x000000011153fb04: mov    0x8(%r12,%r10,8),%esi          ; implicit exception: dispatches to 0x000000011153ff4e
  0.06%    │  0x000000011153fb09: cmp    $0x237565,%esi                 ;   {metadata(&apos;com/nikoskatsanos/benchmarks/loops/SingleElementLoopBenchmark$Dispatcher$1&apos;)}
  0.00%    │  0x000000011153fb0f: jne    0x000000011153fcc2
  3.93%    │  0x000000011153fb15: lea    (%r12,%r10,8),%rax             ;*invokeinterface get {reexecute=0 rethrow=0 return_oop=0}
           │                                                            ; - com.benchmarks.loops.SingleElementLoopBenchmark$Dispatcher::invokeInLoop@20 (line 45)
           │                                                            ; - com.benchmarks.loops.SingleElementLoopBenchmark::singleElementLoopInvocation@5 (line 28)
           │                                                            ; - com.benchmarks.loops.generated.SingleElementLoopBenchmark_singleElementLoopInvocation_jmhTest::singleElementLoopInvocation_thrpt_jmhStub@17 (line 121)
  0.06%    │  0x000000011153fb19: mov    0x10(%rax),%r10d               ;*getfield size {reexecute=0 rethrow=0 return_oop=0}
           │                                                            ; - java.util.ArrayList::get@2 (line 458)
           │                                                            ; - com.benchmarks.loops.SingleElementLoopBenchmark$Dispatcher::invokeInLoop@20 (line 45)
           │                                                            ; - com.benchmarks.loops.SingleElementLoopBenchmark::singleElementLoopInvocation@5 (line 28)
           │                                                            ; - com.benchmarks.loops.generated.SingleElementLoopBenchmark_singleElementLoopInvocation_jmhTest::singleElementLoopInvocation_thrpt_jmhStub@17 (line 121)
  0.11%    │  0x000000011153fb1d: test   %r10d,%r10d
           │  0x000000011153fb20: jl     0x000000011153fcf6             ;*invokestatic checkIndex {reexecute=0 rethrow=0 return_oop=0}
           │                                                            ; - java.util.Objects::checkIndex@3 (line 372)
           │                                                            ; - java.util.ArrayList::get@5 (line 458)
           │                                                            ; - com.benchmarks.loops.SingleElementLoopBenchmark$Dispatcher::invokeInLoop@20 (line 45)
           │                                                            ; - com.benchmarks.loops.SingleElementLoopBenchmark::singleElementLoopInvocation@5 (line 28)
           │                                                            ; - com.benchmarks.loops.generated.SingleElementLoopBenchmark_singleElementLoopInvocation_jmhTest::singleElementLoopInvocation_thrpt_jmhStub@17 (line 121)
  0.28%    │  0x000000011153fb26: cmp    %r10d,%r9d
  0.00%    │  0x000000011153fb29: jae    0x000000011153fc1c
  3.97%    │  0x000000011153fb2f: mov    0x14(%rax),%r10d               ;*getfield elementData {reexecute=0 rethrow=0 return_oop=0}
           │                                                            ; - java.util.ArrayList::elementData@1 (line 442)
           │                                                            ; - java.util.ArrayList::get@11 (line 459)
           │                                                            ; - com.benchmarks.loops.SingleElementLoopBenchmark$Dispatcher::invokeInLoop@20 (line 45)
           │                                                            ; - com.benchmarks.loops.SingleElementLoopBenchmark::singleElementLoopInvocation@5 (line 28)
           │                                                            ; - com.benchmarks.loops.generated.SingleElementLoopBenchmark_singleElementLoopInvocation_jmhTest::singleElementLoopInvocation_thrpt_jmhStub@17 (line 121)
  0.05%    │  0x000000011153fb33: mov    %r9d,%ebp                      ;*invokestatic checkIndex {reexecute=0 rethrow=0 return_oop=0}
           │                                                            ; - java.util.Objects::checkIndex@3 (line 372)
           │                                                            ; - java.util.ArrayList::get@5 (line 458)
           │                                                            ; - com.benchmarks.loops.SingleElementLoopBenchmark$Dispatcher::invokeInLoop@20 (line 45)
           │                                                            ; - com.benchmarks.loops.SingleElementLoopBenchmark::singleElementLoopInvocation@5 (line 28)
           │                                                            ; - com.benchmarks.loops.generated.SingleElementLoopBenchmark_singleElementLoopInvocation_jmhTest::singleElementLoopInvocation_thrpt_jmhStub@17 (line 121)
  0.08%    │  0x000000011153fb36: mov    0xc(%r12,%r10,8),%esi          ; implicit exception: dispatches to 0x000000011153ff62
  1.27%    │  0x000000011153fb3b: cmp    %esi,%ebp
           │  0x000000011153fb3d: jae    0x000000011153fc5a
  3.94%    │  0x000000011153fb43: shl    $0x3,%r10
  0.05%    │  0x000000011153fb47: mov    0x10(%r10,%rbp,4),%r9d         ;*aaload {reexecute=0 rethrow=0 return_oop=0}
           │                                                            ; - java.util.ArrayList::elementData@5 (line 442)
           │                                                            ; - java.util.ArrayList::get@11 (line 459)
           │                                                            ; - com.benchmarks.loops.SingleElementLoopBenchmark$Dispatcher::invokeInLoop@20 (line 45)
           │                                                            ; - com.benchmarks.loops.SingleElementLoopBenchmark::singleElementLoopInvocation@5 (line 28)
           │                                                            ; - com.benchmarks.loops.generated.SingleElementLoopBenchmark_singleElementLoopInvocation_jmhTest::singleElementLoopInvocation_thrpt_jmhStub@17 (line 121)
  1.71%    │  0x000000011153fb4c: mov    0x8(%r12,%r9,8),%r10d          ; implicit exception: dispatches to 0x000000011153ff72
 17.85%    │  0x000000011153fb51: cmp    $0x237522,%r10d                ;   {metadata(&apos;com/nikoskatsanos/benchmarks/loops/SingleElementLoopBenchmark$Listener&apos;)}
  0.00%    │  0x000000011153fb58: jne    0x000000011153fef6             ;*checkcast {reexecute=0 rethrow=0 return_oop=0}
           │                                                            ; - com.benchmarks.loops.SingleElementLoopBenchmark$Dispatcher::invokeInLoop@25 (line 45)
           │                                                            ; - com.benchmarks.loops.SingleElementLoopBenchmark::singleElementLoopInvocation@5 (line 28)
           │                                                            ; - com.benchmarks.loops.generated.SingleElementLoopBenchmark_singleElementLoopInvocation_jmhTest::singleElementLoopInvocation_thrpt_jmhStub@17 (line 121)
  3.79%    │  0x000000011153fb5e: mov    %rdi,0x18(%rsp)
  0.02%    │  0x000000011153fb63: mov    %r8d,0x10(%rsp)
  0.02%    │  0x000000011153fb68: mov    %rbx,0x8(%rsp)
  0.19%    │  0x000000011153fb6d: mov    %r11,0x50(%rsp)
  3.95%    │  0x000000011153fb72: mov    %rdx,0x60(%rsp)
  0.02%    │  0x000000011153fb77: mov    %rcx,(%rsp)
  0.03%    │  0x000000011153fb7b: mov    %r13,0x58(%rsp)
  0.36%    │  0x000000011153fb80: mov    %rdx,%rsi
  3.78%    │  0x000000011153fb83: mov    $0x1,%edx
  0.01%    │  0x000000011153fb88: vzeroupper
  4.05%    │  0x000000011153fb8b: callq  0x00000001114c2900             ; ImmutableOopMap{[80]=Oop [88]=Oop [96]=Oop [0]=Oop [16]=NarrowOop [24]=Oop }
           │                                                            ;*invokevirtual consume {reexecute=0 rethrow=0 return_oop=0}
           │                                                            ; - com.benchmarks.loops.SingleElementLoopBenchmark$Listener::performAction@2 (line 53)
           │                                                            ; - com.benchmarks.loops.SingleElementLoopBenchmark$Dispatcher::invokeInLoop@29 (line 45)
           │                                                            ; - com.benchmarks.loops.SingleElementLoopBenchmark::singleElementLoopInvocation@5 (line 28)
           │                                                            ; - com.benchmarks.loops.generated.SingleElementLoopBenchmark_singleElementLoopInvocation_jmhTest::singleElementLoopInvocation_thrpt_jmhStub@17 (line 121)
           │                                                            ;   {optimized virtual_call}
  0.98%    │  0x000000011153fb90: mov    0x10(%rsp),%r8d
  3.61%    │  0x000000011153fb95: mov    0x10(%r12,%r8,8),%r10d         ;*getfield singleListenerList {reexecute=0 rethrow=0 return_oop=0}
           │                                                            ; - com.benchmarks.loops.SingleElementLoopBenchmark$Dispatcher::invokeInLoop@4 (line 44)
           │                                                            ; - com.benchmarks.loops.SingleElementLoopBenchmark::singleElementLoopInvocation@5 (line 28)
           │                                                            ; - com.benchmarks.loops.generated.SingleElementLoopBenchmark_singleElementLoopInvocation_jmhTest::singleElementLoopInvocation_thrpt_jmhStub@17 (line 121)
  0.24%    │  0x000000011153fb9a: mov    0x8(%r12,%r10,8),%r9d          ; implicit exception: dispatches to 0x000000011153ff9e
  0.74%    │  0x000000011153fb9f: inc    %ebp                           ;*iinc {reexecute=0 rethrow=0 return_oop=0}
           │                                                            ; - com.benchmarks.loops.SingleElementLoopBenchmark$Dispatcher::invokeInLoop@32 (line 44)
           │                                                            ; - com.benchmarks.loops.SingleElementLoopBenchmark::singleElementLoopInvocation@5 (line 28)
           │                                                            ; - com.benchmarks.loops.generated.SingleElementLoopBenchmark_singleElementLoopInvocation_jmhTest::singleElementLoopInvocation_thrpt_jmhStub@17 (line 121)
  0.04%    │  0x000000011153fba1: cmp    $0x237565,%r9d                 ;   {metadata(&apos;com/nikoskatsanos/benchmarks/loops/SingleElementLoopBenchmark$Dispatcher$1&apos;)}
  0.00%    │  0x000000011153fba8: jne    0x000000011153fd36
  3.60%    │  0x000000011153fbae: lea    (%r12,%r10,8),%r11             ;*invokeinterface size {reexecute=0 rethrow=0 return_oop=0}
           │                                                            ; - com.benchmarks.loops.SingleElementLoopBenchmark$Dispatcher::invokeInLoop@7 (line 44)
           │                                                            ; - com.benchmarks.loops.SingleElementLoopBenchmark::singleElementLoopInvocation@5 (line 28)
           │                                                            ; - com.benchmarks.loops.generated.SingleElementLoopBenchmark_singleElementLoopInvocation_jmhTest::singleElementLoopInvocation_thrpt_jmhStub@17 (line 121)
  0.11%    │  0x000000011153fbb2: mov    0x10(%r11),%r9d
  0.35%    │  0x000000011153fbb6: cmp    %r9d,%ebp
           ╰  0x000000011153fbb9: jge    0x000000011153fa9f             ;*if_icmpge {reexecute=0 rethrow=0 return_oop=0}
                                                                        ; - com.benchmarks.loops.SingleElementLoopBenchmark$Dispatcher::invokeInLoop@12 (line 44)
                                                                        ; - com.benchmarks.loops.SingleElementLoopBenchmark::singleElementLoopInvocation@5 (line 28)
                                                                        ; - com.benchmarks.loops.generated.SingleElementLoopBenchmark_singleElementLoopInvocation_jmhTest::singleElementLoopInvocation_thrpt_jmhStub@17 (line 121)
              0x000000011153fbbf: mov    %ebp,%r9d
              0x000000011153fbc2: mov    0x58(%rsp),%r13
              0x000000011153fbc7: mov    (%rsp),%rcx
              0x000000011153fbcb: mov    0x60(%rsp),%rdx
              0x000000011153fbd0: mov    0x50(%rsp),%r11
              0x000000011153fbd5: mov    0x8(%rsp),%rbx
....................................................................................................
```

I would like some help if possible to understand the above two outputs. From the very little I understand it seems that when looping, the program is paying quite a cost of checking the size of the array list in order to perform the loop and also cost of casting the object to the appropriate type, due to the list generics. I cannot really understand if the loops gets unrolled, but I believe it does?

Would be grateful if someone understand the above output and can throw some pointers to what is happening.

Comment: `vzeroupper` is insane here; there's no use of YMM AVX registers inside the loop.  (It's not slow on CPUs other than KNL, but it's more a sign that the JIT doesn't see through a lot of stuff).  Clearly there are huge missed optimizations here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You measure an operation that does virtually nothing vs. an operation that involves at least four dependent memory loads:

- ArrayList.size
- ArrayList.elementData
- elementData.length
- elementData[0]

plus at least one bounds check. I say "at least", because that's what the best optimizing compiler could probably do. HotSpot, however, performs two bound checks: one in ArrayList.get(), another for elementData array access.

Furthermore, ArrayList holds an array of Objects, so in order to get an instance of `Listener` from the list, an object needs to be cast to the target type. That's one more memory load plus the type check.

Look at the benchmark scores from a different angle: a single element list is not 2.5x slower, but rather 3 nanoseconds longer:

```
Benchmark                                               Mode  Cnt  Score   Error  Units
SingleElementLoopBenchmark.directInvocation             avgt    5  2,340 ± 0,095  ns/op
SingleElementLoopBenchmark.singleElementLoopInvocation  avgt    5  5,283 ± 0,074  ns/op
```

*3 nanoseconds!* It's just 6 CPU cycles of a 2 GHz core. The light can travel less than 1 metre in 3 nanoseconds. Did you really expect the overhead of ArrayList less than that? No matter how low the overhead is, if comparing it with no overhead at all, the ratio could be infinitely large.

Comment: Andrei, first of all thank you for your time and the detailed explanation. My main goal here was to actually understand what was the overhead of the loop approach, which you explained thoroughly. You do have a point when saying I might be looking the results from a wrong perspective. I was just trying to weight the pros and cons for a specific use case that might cause excessive number of calls in short period. Thank you again.